# Homeomorphism between normal space and subspace of $[0,1]^k$

Tags: general-topology

Given $A$ is normal and has a basis $B$ in which $|B|=k$. Show that $A$ is homeomorphic to a subspace of $[0,1]^k$.

**My Thought** I was thinking of applying the Jones's lemma here, but I couldn't even show the continuity of $A$, let alone the bijection proof. The hypothesis about the cardinality of $B$ is quite hard for me to use. Can anyone please give me some help on this problem?

Comment: Have you seen a proof of the Urysohn Metrization Theorem?

Comment: @MattSamuel: Yes, I have seen it, but I couldn't find a way to mimic that proof for this problem:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the base in question. Let

$$\mathscr{P}=\{\langle B_0,B_1\rangle\in\mathscr{B}\times\mathscr{B}:\operatorname{cl}B_0\subseteq B_1\}\;.$$

For each $P=\langle B_0,B_1\rangle\in\mathscr{P}$ there is a continuous $f_P:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f_P(x)=0$ for all $x\in\operatorname{cl}B_0$, and $f_P(x)=1$ for all $x\in X\setminus B_1$. Use the functions $f_P$ for $P\in\mathscr{P}$ to build an embedding of $X$ in $[0,1]^{\mathscr{P}}$.

Comment: @Professor Scott: Thank you very much for your helpful hint. I understand that by Urysohn Theorem, there exists such a $f_p$. But I don't see how we can build an embedding, as you suggested, from those functions $f_p$. My apology, but can you please show the remaining part:(

Comment: @user177196: Try sending $x$ to $\langle f_P(x):P\in\mathscr{P}\rangle$, so that the value of $f_P$ at $x$ is the $P$-th coordinate of $h(x)$ (where $h$ is the embedding).

Comment: did you mean $h(x)=(f_{p1}(x), f_{p2}(x),..., f_{p}(x),...)$ for $pi\in \mathscr{P}$. But then I will need to show such a $f_p$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $[0,1]^\mathscr{P}$. How can I show such $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and $f$ is $1-1$ and onto though?

Comment: @user177196: No, you have to show that it’s continuous, $1$-$1$, and that $h[U]$ is open in $h[X]$ for each open $U$ in $X$: in all likelihood it is *not* onto. You show continuity by looking at a basic open set in the product and showing that its inverse image under $h$ is open in $X$; this simply uses the fact that the functions $f_P$ are continuous. You show that $h$ is $1$-$1$ by using the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $X$ and showing that if $x,y\in X$ with $x\ne y$, then there is a $P\in\mathscr{P}$ such that $f_P(x)\ne f_P(y)$. And you finish up by showing that $h[B]$ is ...

Comment: ... open in $h[X]$ for each $B\in\mathscr{B}$, using the definition of $h$ and the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $X$.

Comment: many thanks for your further help, Prof. Scott! Did I understand the definition of h(x) correctly? If not, can you please clarify on the specific form that h will take?

Comment: @user177196: Yes, you’ve understood $h$ correctly, except that you should remember that if $k$ is uncountable, then you can’t actually index $\mathscr{P}$ by the positive integers.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: thanks so much for your great hints! I will try my best to fill out the details. If unfortunately I still got stuck, may I bother you again?

Comment: @user177196: You’re welcome. Yes, of course, though I may be offline a little more than usual this weekend.

Comment: so I was able to show open and 1-1, but I'm not quite sure how $h[B]$ is open in $h[X]$. I know that since $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for $X$, $X$ is a union of basic elements $B$. But we only have $f_{p}$ is continuous, not open, so $f_{p}$ does not necessarily map basic open sets of X into basic open sets of f[X]??

Comment: @user177196: That’s true. But one can show that if $x\in B\in\mathscr{B}$, then there is an open nbhd $U$ of $h(x)$ in $[0,1]^{\mathscr{P}}$ such that $U\cap h[X]\subseteq h[B]$, which shows that $h[B]$ is open in $h[Y]$. HINT: Choose $B_0\in\mathscr{B}$ so that $x\in B_0\subseteq\operatorname{cl}B_0\subseteq B$, let $P=\langle B_0,B\rangle$, and choose a basic open $U$ that restricts only on the $P$ coordinate of $[0,1]^{\mathscr{P}}$.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: I almost got it, but what does $<B_0,B>$ mean?

Comment: @user177196: Ordered pair of basic open sets, as in the definition of $\mathscr{P}$ in my answer; you’re probably more familiar with the notation $(B_0,B)$ (and in my answer $(B_0,B_1)$).

Comment: @Prof. Scott: I finally got it!!! Many thanks for your awesome hints, patience and skills!

Comment: @user177196: Excellent – you’re welcome!

Comment: @Prof. Scott: Btw, I think you made a typo in defining "$f_{p}(x)=1$ for all $x\in X-B_1$". Shouldn't $B_0$ be used here instead of $B_1$? Also, from the definition of normal, the  $\mathscr{P}$ should have cl $B_0$ is not in $B_1$ and cl $B_1$ is not in $B_0$? And apparently, I just realized that you didn't touch the hypothesis $|B|=k$. Did I miss something from your solution:P

Comment: Otherwise, the Urysohn's theorem doesn't work for $B_0$ and $X-B1$, since they are not closed & disjoint sets in X.

Comment: @user177196: No, I defined $f_P$ the way I intended. The disjoint closed sets are $\operatorname{cl}B_0$ and $X\setminus\operatorname{cl}B_1$. I could have said that $f_P(x)=0$ if $x\in\operatorname{cl}B_0$, but that certainly implies what I did say, which is all that one really needs. However, I’ll change that to clear up the possible confusion. When I said ‘Let $\mathscr{B}$ be the base in question’, I intended it to be understood that I was talking about the one that you were given, of cardinality $|k|$. Since $|\mathscr{P}|=|\mathscr{B}|$, the argument shows that you can use the ...

Comment: ... cardinality of any base here.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: thanks so much for your clarification. However, I would like to clarify one thing: how do you know that $X - cl(B_1)$ is a closed set? Certainly it's disjoint from $cl(B_0)$ by the condition you imposed, but to apply Urysohn's lemman, we also need disjoint. And I think you assume $B_0, B_1$ are closed subsets in $B$?

Comment: @user177196: Sorry: I must have had closures on the brain when I wrote that. That should of course be $X\setminus B_1$.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: how do we know if $X-B_1$ is closed then? The Urysohn's lemma that you apply to show the existence of continuous function $f_p$ requires both sets are closed.

Comment: @user177196: $X\setminus B_1$ is the complement of an open set: $B_1\in\mathscr{B}$ is open.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: I just realized that, and intended to delete my dumb question:P My last question: since we want to show $h$ is a homeomorphism, why don't we need $h$ is bijective based on def. of homeomorphism, but rather only $1-1$?

Comment: @user177196: Because in general $h$ cannot map $X$ **onto** $[0,1]^{\mathscr{P}}$; $h$ is a bijection (and homeomorphism) from $X$ to $h[X]$, but not in general from $X$ to $[0,1]^{\mathscr{P}}$.

Comment: @Prof. Scott: many thanks for your helpful clarifications. So this concludes our problem because $h[X]$ is a subspace of $[0,1]^{\mathscr{P}}$?

Comment: @user177196: Yes, and that’s all that you’re asked to get.